# How to mark off months using an Array of dates in BASH

Tags: bash, date

I'm stuck with an issue that probably seems to have too many conflicting variables making it unfeasible. So I would like any suggestions, or advise if it really is not feasible to implement.

Right now I have a script that takes in a value, for example xx-xx-160416-xx.... 
This script sifts out the date and sorts the date in ascending order.

So for each of these dates, it will cover a total of 3 months. 
For e.g. 010416 will mean that I will mark off January, February and March of 2016.

and I do not wish to have duplicates, which means if I have the 3 following values

```
010416
010516
010716
```

I will only keep 010416 and 010716 as 010516 is not needed anymore.

I understand that this might seem like a bit too much, but I would appreciate any help I can get from here. Even pointing me in the right direction.

Currently my script looks like this

```
awk '{print $1}' /home/1551391/restore > restore1
awk -F '-' '{print $3}' /home/1551391/restore1 > restore
uniq /home/1551391/restore > restore1
declare -a array
for file in `cat /home/1551391/restore1`
do
  [[ $file =~ '([[:digit:]]{2})([[:digit:]]{2})([[:digit:]]{2})' ]] && \
    {
      index="${BASH_REMATCH[3]}${BASH_REMATCH[2]}${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
      array[$index]="$file"
}
done

for i in "${array[@]}"
do
  echo $i
done
```

and the result of this currently looks something like this.

```
$ ./Dates.sh
050915
311015
071115
051215
020116
300116
050316
160416
```

Comment: It's not clear even what constitutes a date or what you mean by "mark off".  Is 010416 a value which means January 4th, 2016?  Some of your other examples look like they have the even wackier mmddyy format.

Comment: If you can clarify your requirements, I'm guessing the entire Bash script can be replaced with a much simpler Awk script.  That would coincidentally fix the http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls bingo.